# Excel Service Data Refresh Issue in SharePoint 2013 Online Office 365

Tags: sharepoint-online, excel-services

I am using Excel Services in Office 365 SharePoint Online to show Workbook Pivot Reports data pulled from SQL Server 2008.

I have used Secure Store for saving Database Credentials & Configure Authorization Settings as Secure Store Target Application ID.

I have saved ODC file in Data Connection Library. All is working well but when I try to Refresh Data it gives me below Error:

> "External Data Refresh Failed. We were unable to refresh one  or more data connections in this workbook."

Can anyone please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: have you managed to solve this issue? I'm having the same.